Terminate PHP shell_exec process after certain amount of time
If I execute a command in PHP shell_exec and don't want to wait for 10mins for it to finish, is there a way to terminate it?

simply add & (or other similar syntax) at the last to tell the system that the process should run in the background

I still need to make it synchronous, so ill wait but until 10mins only. Ill terminate it after 10mins

I see. then you may use ulimit . You may refer to this post

@EmmanuelSayson what OS you are using?
